# How to choose an appropiate antenna?

Tags: rf, antenna, bluetooth-low-energy, component-selection, transmission

I want to increase the Bluetooth Low Energy transmission range of my ESP32 with IPEX connector.

How can I select the right antenna?

Do I have to take a look only at a 2,4 GHz WiFi antenna, the antenna gain and the right impedance or do I have to take something else into account?

Comment: What do you need to communicate with? One device? Several? How are they placed, both vertically and horizontally? What is the other device? Can you pick the antenna for that as well? Are you indoors or outdoors? What kind of range are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Impedance and frequency, other are not relevant. Gain is possible with directed antenna or with antenna that has shaped radiation pattern. You should first elaborate what radiation pattern you would like.

Example of omnidirectional antenna pattern:

[image]